# not found the url in laravel when use prefix

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I use route group and prefix in Laravel

```
Route::name("admin.")->prefix("admin")->group(function (){
    Route::get("/",function (){dd("test");});
});
```

http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin

but this url don't work and return 404 :(

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO ... would you happen to have a folder named 'admin' in the 'public' folder?

Comment: yes , thank you , I found the problem